# Dockerfile ignoring the PATH environment variable

Tags: node.js, docker

Looks like during the build, the PATH environment variable is ignored. I have my Dockerfile like this:

```
COPY my_app /opt/my_app
RUN echo $PATH
RUN node --version

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

..., and it gaves me build-time error, saying:

> /bin/sh: node: command not found
>   The command '/bin/sh -c node --version' returned a non-zero code: 127

The line RUN echo $PATH shows me that node-dir is already in the PATH, so why it's not being picked up by docker build?

```
/usr/local/nvm/v6.9.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you'll need to configure NVM before using `node`.

Something like this should work:

```
COPY my_app /opt/my_app
RUN echo $PATH
RUN nvm use 6.9.0 
# or, if you want this version to be the default `node`, use: 
# `nvm alias default 6.9.0`
RUN node --version

CMD ["node", "app.js"]
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$PATH` variable is available from your host environment only at build time, not at runtime. And I would strongly discourage its use at build time anyway as you are making machine-specific images then.

The [`docker run` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/env-environment-variables) clearly states which environment variables are set at runtime to which values by default. Anything else needs to be set manually. This is what it says:

> When a new container is created, Docker will set the following environment variables automatically:

```
HOME    Set based on the value of USER
HOSTNAME    The hostname associated with the container
PATH    Includes popular directories, such as :/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
TERM    xterm if the container is allocated a pseudo-TTY
```